# C# Registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have a probleme with my project c#, I want register the user, but it's not work!. Someone know how can I resolve this probleme, thanks.

> errorSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'D:\ASP_WORKSPACES\LOGIN\LOGIN\APP_DATA\DATABASE.MDF.dbo.User'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated. à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) à System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) à System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() à Registration.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) dans D:\asp_workspaces\login\login\Registration.aspx.cs:ligne 49 ClientConnectionId :b0d4edc1-2ade-4417-8d9d-7f6e8befc17e Error Number :515,State :2,Class :16

**The code of Register.aspx.cs**

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string insertQuery = ("insert into [User](username,email,password,country)values (@username,@email,@password,@country)");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", country.SelectedItem.ToString());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Response.Write("User Successfully Registered");

        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("error" + ex.ToString());
    }

}
```

**Registration.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">User name</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="username" ErrorMessage="Username is required." ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">E-mail</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="email" ErrorMessage="Email is required." ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="email" ErrorMessage="You must enter the valid email." ForeColor="#FF3300" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">Password</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">Confirm Password</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="confpassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="confpassword" ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <br />
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="password" ControlToValidate="confpassword" ErrorMessage="Password must be some" ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:CompareValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">Country</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="country" runat="server" Width="180px">
                        <asp:ListItem>Select country</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>USA</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>UK</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Germany</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>France</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="country" ErrorMessage="Select the country name." ForeColor="#FF3300" InitialValue="Select country"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style5">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
                    <input id="Reset1" type="reset" value="reset" /></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style5">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Query for create database sql in visual studion 2017**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
[Id]       INT        NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
[username] NCHAR (20) NULL DEFAULT u,
[email]    NCHAR (20) NULL DEFAULT e,
[password] NCHAR (20) NULL DEFAULT p,
[country]  NCHAR (20) NULL DEFAULT c,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Don't store passwords as plain text!

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, you cannot insert `null` into the column `Id`. The simplest solution would be to change the table definition so that column is an [`IDENTITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) column which automatically increments values as you insert new rows. So change your definition to this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [Id]       INT        NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1), 
    [username] NCHAR (20) NULL,
    [email]    NCHAR (20) NULL,
    [password] NCHAR (20) NULL,
    [country]  NCHAR (20) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: There is a Default value for Id column. Will that not insert 1 if not sent in insert query?

Comment: @SurjitSD Actually yes, but the error being given indicates the table definition doesn't match what is in the database. In fact, it doesn't even work so I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a table Users with a Id column that cannot have null value ( as Error explains).

You either need to send some value for Id column from insert query like

```
Insert into [User] ([Id], [username], …) values (@id, @username……)
```

And add in parameters same way other user values are added. 
OR
Make the database column Id as Identity with incerment `Seed value =1`.

Assuming Id will be your primary key column, assigning `default =1` will not be very good choice.